# vue template with v-if base on ajax result

Tags: templates, vue.js

i daymic render template element with ajax function change the data,
but exactly it doesn't update the view immedidately, here is the pseude code：

```
<template v-if="userInfo.nickName">
  <div class="base-info" v-show="userInfo.nickName">
    <p>欢迎，{{this.userInfo.nickName}} <a href="javascript:;" @click="logout">退出</a></p>
  </div>
</template>
<template v-else>
  <div class="base-crud">
    <el-button @click="toLogin" type="primary">登录</el-button>
    <el-button @click="toRegister" type="primary">注册</el-button>
  </div>
</template>

mounted() {
  // the updateUserInfo is an vuex action fn, the userInfo was come from vuex store data
  ajaxFn().then((data) => this.updateUserInfo(data));
}
```

Comment: "it doesn't update the view immediately" Because it's an async call probably? What's your question?

Comment: i have found the question,
`Object.assign(state.userInfo, data)` replace to `state.userInfo = Object.assign({}, state.userInfo, data)`;

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:
just replace `Object.assign(state.userInfo, data)` to `state.userInfo = Object.assign({}, state.userInfo, data)` in the store action fn;
It's my fault , sorry!!